# Profile Picture visible from machine where I add it, but not from other machines

Tags: support, profile-picture

Day 1: At home, I created my Stack Exchange Account and added profile picture: it was perfectly visible.

Day 2 (morning): In the office, after I logged into my Stack Exchange account, the profile picture was not available. I added a picture from the office at that time: profile picture not available but perfectly added.

Day 2 (evening): At home, I saw the profile picture which I added in my office.

Why?

Comment: How did you added profile picture, from home ?

Comment: May be at your office there are some site restriction. Right now I can see your profile pic but I can not see TRiG is Timothy Richard Green's profile pic.

Comment: Oh. I guess that. Thanks.

Comment: @Kedarnath You missed your repuation due to said answer in the comment section.

Comment: My image (on this site) is from Gravatar. Udan Pirappu's is from imgur. So it sounds like Udan has imgur blocked, and you, @Kedarnath, have Gravatar blocked.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen, Correct, I was just trying to recollect that "Gravatar" word. It just flashed from my memory at that time.

Comment: how to find the picture from `imgur` , `gravatar`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean by *profile picture not available but perfectly added*?

Here’s what I think happened:

1. You uploaded a picture from home. It worked fine.
2. You went into the office. Your picture is still working, but the filtering in the office stops you from seeing it.
3. You uploaded a new picture from the office. It was uploaded correctly (“perfectly added”) but you still couldn’t see it (“not available”).
4. You went home, where pictures are not blocked, and you could see your new picture.

If my diagnosis is correct, the problem is that your office blocks imgur. That’s where profile pictures are stored when they’re uploaded directly from your profile. If you delete your profile picture, it will instead load one from Facebook (if you created your account by logging in through Facebook) or Gravatar (otherwise). You could try (from home) deleting your profile picture and using Gravatar instead. See whether that works.

Ideally, though, you’d get your office to unblock the domain `i.stack.imgur.com`. A lot of Stack Exchange images are loaded from that domain, not just trivial stuff like profile pictures.

Comment: ok. I got it...